# Incorrect notice on flagging answer for moderation action

Tags: bug, flags

I submitted a custom flag for plagiarism on an answer:

> Entire answer is copied verbatim from https://alexvanderbist.com/2019/how-migrations-might-be-slowing-down-your-laravel-tests/

I received this popup when I pushed the submit button:

[image: Think this question should be migrated to another site? Please first check that it is clearly-written and on-topic for the site you're recommending. If you aren't an experienced member of that site, please take some time to read their help center first; rejected migrations are frustrating to both askers and the good people on the site who must reject it. Thanks!]

Pushing the button again submitted the flag as expected. Not sure if this was a one-time thing or a bug that's cropped up this morning.

Comment: What was your flag text? Did it have words like "move" in it?

Comment: It did, yes; I've edited to add the flag text. That makes sense that it would look for migration requests in flag text. I was flagging the answer and not the question though.

Comment: Ah, almost certainly "migration" in the URL is what triggered the notice. The "is this a migration flag?" check is rather naïve.

Comment: A quick test indicates this is likely. A flag with the flag text: `Ignore this flag if I don't retract it fast enough, I'm checking if in a flag triggers a check re: https://meta.migrations.com/q/415737/3270037` also triggers it.

Comment: Ohh yeah. I got this today too and I was wondering how on earth I triggered this, but I think I used a word like "move" too